# How to get the unique elements of an array with a maximum value of attribute

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
[{id:1, price:10},{id:2, price:9},{id:3, price:8},{id:1, price:7}]
```

Now, how to get the array with unique id's, but in case of choosing between two objects with the same id's get the maximum value (`{id:1, price:10}`)?

Expected result:

```
[{:id=>1, :price=>10}, {:id=>2, :price=>9}, {:id=>3, :price=>8}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this, maybe?

```
a = [
    {id:1, price:10},
    {id:2, price:9},
    {id:3, price:8},
    {id:1, price:7}
]

b = a.group_by{|h| h[:id]}. 
      map{|_, v| v.max_by {|el| el[:price]}}

b # => [{:id=>1, :price=>10}, {:id=>2, :price=>9}, {:id=>3, :price=>8}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

```
a = [{id:1, price:10},{id:2, price:9},{id:3, price:8},{id:1, price:7}]
a.sort_by { |h| -h[:price] }.uniq { |h| h[:id] }
# => [{:id=>1, :price=>10}, {:id=>2, :price=>9}, {:id=>3, :price=>8}]
```

Comment: @Abdo Yeah!! First sort it.. maximum entries will be arranged by prices, Then collect uniq elements by id.. :) :)